# Send long sms via Opensmpp

Tags: java, sms, smpp, opensmpp

I use opensmpp library for sending sms, but I cannot find documentation or example of sending long messages. I want to send long messages by splitting and using UDH (because it's sms gate requirement). Where can I find documentation or example for Opensmpp java library?

Comment: Take a look at the following page on Opensmpp's Github page: https://github.com/OpenSmpp/opensmpp/issues/5

Comment: Thx, but how can I set UDHI flag via opensmpp?

Comment: Have a look at [this article](https://itprobes.wordpress.com/2009/09/05/hello-world/) on concatenated SMS. Basically you need to add the flag to the request, like `smRequest.setEsmClass((byte)Data.SM_UDH_GSM);` and split your message into chunks of 153 bytes so that the additional header can be included. HTH

Comment: Great to hear! Would you be so kind to close this question so that it does not remain unanswered? Thx!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good to hear it worked! As a short summary, this would be the way to add additional header information for multipart/concatenated SMS delivery using OpenSmpp:

```
SubmitSM smRequest = new SubmitSM();
smRequest.setEsmClass((byte)Data.SM_UDH_GSM);
```

The above code was taken from [this article](https://itprobes.wordpress.com/2009/09/05/hello-world/) about multi-part SMS that includes sample code and extended technical details.